# JVM Crashing few minutes after application starts

Tags: java, debugging, crash, jvm, jvm-crash

JVM is getting crashed few minutes after the application starts. This application is working fine in other machines. This application uses javax.print apis. Could the faulty printer dlls be culprit? How to resolve this issue?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fff089c997d, pid=424, tid=20976
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (11.0.10+9) (build 11.0.10+9)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (11.0.10+9, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x2c997d]
#
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8253 CPU @ 2.20GHz, 4 cores, 7G,  Windows Server 2012 R2 , 64 bit Build 9600 (6.3.9600.20625)
Time: Fri Nov 11 08:13:53 2022 Central Standard Time elapsed time: 98.393674 seconds (0d 0h 1m 38s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000f2716a2800):  GCTaskThread "GC Thread#3" [stack: 0x000000f273d80000,0x000000f273e80000] [id=20976]

Stack: [0x000000f273d80000,0x000000f273e80000],  sp=0x000000f273e7ded0,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x2c997d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x73e694]
V  [jvm.dll+0x65856d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x73efcc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x6595c4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x7a9490]
V  [jvm.dll+0x739ba4]
V  [jvm.dll+0x5f2466]
C  [ucrtbase.DLL+0x1c1ae]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x13d2]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x15504]


siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0x0000000000000000
```

I tried running the application with increased java heap space still it crashed.

Comment: You might want to double check the JRE version on this machine and ensure it's the same version of the other machines (where it does not crash) - Yes, printer drivers could be an issue but I don't have enough info in the question to tell for certain

Comment: Well, you can see all DLLs involved in the crashed thread and there’s no printer DLL involved. While this doesn’t prove that there’s no relationship, it makes it rather unlikely.

Comment: Could be related to [JDK-8231430](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8231430) or [JDK-8258987](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8258987)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the faulty drivers of few printers. After removing those printers the application started working fine.
Java should be able handle these scenarios better!